# Behat user login in separate features

Tags: bdd, behat, mink

I've just started using Behat + Mink with symfony session by default for testing my app. I have two separate features in *.feature files and in both of them I login user.

My problem is that they both pass while being executed separately, but can't be passed while executed together with **php app/console -e=test behat @MyBundle**

The second feature is failing because user keeps being logged in after the first one.
How should I properly logout user or Mink should do that for me?

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept it. That way it gets out of the unanswered question queue.

Comment: @t3node thanks, didn't know I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution! 
reading https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1759 helped, all I needed was adding 
**test: ~** to **framework:**. It solved problem with session warnings like "the session id is too long or contains illegal characters" and problem with user login in separate features.